# Android Card View Shadow in each side

Tags: android, cardview

I want to have same shadow on each side of card view like following image on both lollipop devices and above :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you. You can try using the `app:cardElevation="8dp"` attribute and change the value to suit your needs. Remember to add this attribute the parent layout first though `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

example below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As for the rounded corners you can use the `app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"` and adjust the value to suit your needs.

Comment: card view  implements material design guide lines and put shadows with light enabled on top of it i had tried cardElevation but it's not helped me

Answer (score -1):

The key is use  android:elevation="@dimen/_4sdp".

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white"
    android:elevation="@dimen/_4sdp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_8sdp">
```